# Extract the top corner position of QToolButton Widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to extract the cordinates of a toolbutton. So when there is a popup it always starts from the top left corner of the widget. I am doing something like this

```
menu_something->popup(mapToGlobal(ui.toolButton->pos()));
```

However the menu shows up no where close to the toolButton. Any suggestions ?

Comment: shouldnt it be enough to just set the popups parent to be the toolbutton?

Comment: No I would like to align them. By default they would be drop downs. I would like them sideways

Comment: we used this, see my answer, for a push combobox. The dialog always opens up over the pushbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running with QDialog (pushable and styleable ComboBox Dialog):
Get coordinates by calling this in a subclass of QToolButton

```
QPoint mypoint = QWidget::mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0));
```

and use

```
QRect myrect;
myrect.setCoords(topleft.x(),topleft.y(),topleft.x()+width,10);
YourPopupDialog.setGeomentry(myrect);
YourPopupDialog.setFocus();
YourPopupDialog.show();
```

to position the dialog upon the button.

Edit for use with QMenu running in slot conntected to clicked():

```
QMenu menu;
menu.addAction("Text 0");
menu.addAction("Text 1");

menu.exec(ui->toolButtonMenuButton->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0)));
```

Comment: mypoint is topleft in global coordinates, edited to show toolbutton instead of qwidget. We do have a subclass of the button, therefor 0,0 is out topleft corner

Comment: I would recommend createing a subclass of QToolButton to generate a independent widget called dropdownbutton for example. The new widget could hold a list of buttons to be the elements that needed to be drawn in the popup dialog.

Comment: QMenu does not have setGeometry.

Comment: We use a custom QDialog for this. Never tried using QMenu since we run a full touch application and this is actually part of a touch combobox.

Comment: QMenu has setGeometry(const QRect &) inherited

Comment: you need to use a popup with QMenu , your code uses show() which does not work

Comment: We use a custom QDialog, not a QMenu.

Comment: Ill use a QDialog too. If it works for me Ill mark this as answer

Comment: This looks like a lot of extra work with QDialog. I rather stick with QMenu